# How to add a checksum to a string

Tags: ruby, checksum

I'm not sure if this is the correct way of asking. How would I integrate a checksum algorithm into my `label` string. I've looked into parity byte but don't really understand bitwise operators (XOR). I just want an a single character hash of the string.

```
class Integer
def to_bin(width)
    '%0*b' % [width, self]
end

sequence_id = 1.to_bin(24)
library = '3467ACDEFGHJKMNP'

prefix = library[12]

label = prefix + sequence_id.scan(/\d{4}/).reverse.each_with_object(String.new) do |n,obj|
    obj << library[n.to_i(2)]
end

p sequence_id
p label

end
```

Comment: what's the desired output?

Comment: `Digest::MD5.hexdigest(string)`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure *it is not good idea to add checksum right is the string*. Because you have to control some kind of separator **by yourself**. For example my code below has obvious bug, it won't work if original string contains colon `:` character.

Next point is *implementation*. I think, it is better to avoid to implement such algorithms by your self until you are an expert in numeric computation. Best way here it's to use something existing such as *MD5* and *CRC32*. I think MD5 is pretty heavy for that task, so let's use [CRC32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check)

Here is code:

```
require 'zlib'

# This is sample string
strings = ['Hello', 'World', '!']
# Create array where each element
# has original string folowed by colon
# and CRC32 of original string
strings_with_crc = strings.collect do |string|
  string + ':' + Zlib.crc32(string).to_s
end

# Now we can check it!
def crc32check(array)
  array.each do |e|
    string, crc32 = e.split(':')
    print "Checking '#{string}' with '#{crc32}' crc32 sum... "
    puts Zlib.crc32(string) === crc32.to_i ? 'Ok.' : 'FAIL!'
  end
end

puts "Checkin just created array with correct sums:"
crc32check(strings_with_crc)

puts "Checkin new array with wrong sum:"
crc32check(["Hello:42", "World:4223024711", "!:123456"])
```

Here is output of script:

**`Checkin just created array with sums.`**
`Checking 'Hello' with '4157704578' crc32 sum... Ok.
Checking 'World' with '4223024711' crc32 sum... Ok.
Checking '!' with '2657877971' crc32 summ... Ok.`

**`Checkin new array with wrong summ.`**
`Checking 'Hello' with '42' crc32 sum... FAIL!
Checking 'World' with '4223024711' crc32 sum... Ok.
Checking '!' with '123456' crc32 sum... FAIL!`